# Public struct not identified in class?

Tags: c++, class, struct

It seems likt the public struct is not identified in class..... Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


class Human {
public:
    int ID = 32;
    Book humanBook;
    void printHumanId() {
        std::cout << "ID IS : " << ID << std::endl;
    }
};


struct DATE {
    int year;
    int month;
    int date;
};
struct Book {
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int id;
    DATE date;
};

void printBookInfo(Book book) {
    std::cout << "Book Author: " << book.author << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Book Name: " << book.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date : " << book.date.month << "/" << book.date.date << "/" << book.date.year << std::endl;
}

int main() {
     Book book1;
     DATE date1;
     Human Etaferahu;

     std::cout << "Date Of Publishing? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.date;
     std::cout << "Month Of Publishing?" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.month;
     std::cout << "Year Of Publishing?" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.year;


     std::cout << "Book Name ? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.name;

     std::cout << "Book Author ? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.author;

     Etaferahu.printHumanId();
     Etaferahu.humanBook = book1;
     printBookInfo(Etaferahu.humanBook);

    return 0;
}
```

And When i run this code i get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3646   'humanBook': unknown override specifier Struct  c:\users\amanuel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\struct\struct\source.cpp 8   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'humanBook': is not a member of 'Human' Struct  c:\users\amanuel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\struct\struct\source.cpp 53  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Struct  c:\users\amanuel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\struct\struct\source.cpp 8   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2039   'humanBook': is not a member of 'Human' Struct  c:\users\amanuel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\struct\struct\source.cpp 54
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move the definition of the 'Human' class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>




struct DATE {
    int year;
    int month;
    int date;
};
struct Book {
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int id;
    DATE date;
};


class Human {
public:
    int ID = 32;
    Book humanBook;
    void printHumanId() {
        std::cout << "ID IS : " << ID << std::endl;
    }
};



void printBookInfo(Book book) {
    std::cout << "Book Author: " << book.author << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Book Name: " << book.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date : " << book.date.month << "/" << book.date.date << "/" << book.date.year << std::endl;
}

int main() {
     Book book1;
     DATE date1;
     Human Etaferahu;

     std::cout << "Date Of Publishing? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.date;
     std::cout << "Month Of Publishing?" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.month;
     std::cout << "Year Of Publishing?" << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.date.year;


     std::cout << "Book Name ? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.name;

     std::cout << "Book Author ? " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> book1.author;

     Etaferahu.printHumanId();
     Etaferahu.humanBook = book1;
     printBookInfo(Etaferahu.humanBook);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Human {
public:
    int ID = 32;
    Book humanBook;
```

The C++ compiler compiles your code from start to finish. From the begining of the file, to the end of the file. The C++ compiler is not omnipotent. It attempts to compile your file in order, from start to end.

At this point, the C++ compiler has absolutely no clue what "Book" is. The definition of this class appears later in this file, but at this point the compiler has no clue what it is. Hence your compilation errors.

Comment: So How do i fix? If i put it at the bottom then it wont know what class Human is.. and i cant do polymporhism in classes(i think) like i can do with functions

Comment: What do you mean? The "Book" class does not need to know what "Human" is. It doesn't use it. One of us is very confused.

Comment: I Know... but i was just practicing my skills with classes. As i am at that episode of now(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8Luumpu_kE&index=25&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYSyC6w2-rDssprPrEsgtVK)  ... Anyway i can fix this problem or is it a nono?

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong, whtasoever, with your desire to "fix this problem". Make it so.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale You obviously don't put it at the bottom, then int main() would be upset. You have to put it before where it's used, but after the declaration of struct Book, because at the beginning of compilation, the program has no idea what Book is before it is defined

Comment: @AmanuelBogale You have to remember that computers are actually pretty dumb unless we tell them specifically what we want them to do